# Can't see the rig/bones

Tags: rigging, 3d-view, bones

I can't seem to see the rig on a .blend file that I downloaded here. ([This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98874/how-to-best-animate-a-licking-tongue)). I have tried pressing Alt-H in object mode, Alt-H on edit mode, trying to scale the bones up in edit mode. I feel like I'm missing something, like the bones are hidden away inside a layer or something. I downloaded the file to see how the control bones worked with the bendy bones, but I can't seem to find the bones.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable this button. See picture in the right-top corner.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it the first time by changing to the modelling tab, but this is much easier to do.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't used to it either when I upgraded to version 2.8. But once you get used to it, it becomes easy. Have fun and take care!